# How to search a data frame and remove items that match another data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1 = names: Tom, Nick, Pat, Frank
df2 = names: Tom, Nick

I would like to make a df3 by having df2 search through df1 and remove matches so I am left with a new dataframe:
df3 = names: Pat, Frank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
df3 = df1[~df1['names'].isin(df2['names'])]
```

This checks each name in df1 to see if it is in df2, then takes the opposite of the boolean result, and filters df1 based on those resulting bools.